# Where clause on more columns

Tags: javascript, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

In my case I have a text input in which I am typing  the first_name and the_last name. These are columns in User table. The method fires on ajax on change. I am facing the problem: when I type for example 'John Doe' - I cannot query like `User::where("first_name",  "like", "%$query%" )->orWhere("last_name", "like", "%$query%")->get()`. I would need to combine them somehow. The column like "name" would be useful but I don't believe it is right for such functionality.

Comment: You can use `whereRaw()` and concatenate `first_name` and `last_name`, something like `->whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%".$query."%');`

Comment: Don't forget to use bindings to prevent SQL injections: `->whereRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE ?", ['%'.$query.'%'])`